# How do I execute Date from a string?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, date

I am trying to read a file which has dynamic dates in it such as `Date.today` or `(Date.today - 1 )`, and perform my code based on the date requested.

If I have the string defined with the date in quotes it works. When reading the same string from a file it does not. Is there any `eval` function that I need to use to make it work?

```
require 'date'
#Works
abc = "something #{Date.today}"
puts abc
# something 2013-04-19

#does not work
f = File.read("test.txt")
f.each_line { |line|  puts line ; words = line.split("\t")
  puts line
}
```

Contents of the test.txt file:

```
something #{Date.today}
# something #{Date.today}
```

Comment: As it is written... `enter code here`. Or there. Thay would help.

Comment: this is my first post.. i was having issue posting it..so edited it asap. did not expect some one will post this fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to use `eval` to actually evaluate the contents of each line as its read.

But since you will be evaluating arbitrary code you will have to trust that its not malicious code.

So, assuming you trust the file and its lines:

```
require 'date'
f = File.read("test.txt")
f.each_line do |line|
 puts eval("\"#{line}\"")
end
```

Notice the double-quote wrapping, as the "piece of code" you will be evaluating needs to be a "valid" Ruby string (which in turn contains code, so you wrap it in quotes to make it appear to be an actual double-quoted String.

This works if test.txt looks like:

```
Hello, #{Date.today}
Goodbye, #{Date.today}
```

Comment: i might be wrong, i am planning to package it using OCRA so does eval works if i distribute i to others ? . will try my self but wanted to check and confirm.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. i was thinking of this `eval` but using your example of eval worked fine. :)